# Iterate through a function until exact value or certain range is reached

Tags: r, loops, iterator, iteration

I have a function that takes gross income as input and gives me the net income as output:

```
gross_net <- function(gross_income,
                      social_security = 0.2,
                      tax = 0.3){
  net_income <- (gross_income - gross_income * social_security) * (1 - tax)
  net_income
}

gross_net(2000)

> gross_net(2000)
[1] 1120
```

I am looking for some kind of iteration that - if I only have a net income value - "tries out" several gross income values in the gross_net function until it picks the right gross income value that corresponds to the net income value. (I know it would probably be faster to invert the function.)

I thought of a while loop that has a `lower` and `upper` parameter (e.g. the gross income values that are tried out must lie between 1.1 times the `net_income` and 2 times the `net_income`). It should check if `gross_net(net_income * upper)` is higher than my `net_income`, if it is higher then try `gross_net(net_income * lower)`. If this is lower than my `net_income` the try a value a little smaller than the original `upper` parameter and so on until the gross income value that corresponds to the provided net income value is reached (or until the gross income value is in a certain range).

I tried something like

```
net_gross <- function(income){
  test_net_income  <- income
  upper <- 2
  lower <- 1.1
  while(test_income != gross_net(test_net_income)){
    if(gross_net(test_net_income * upper) > income)
      upper <- lower + (upper - lower) * 0.9
    test_income <- income * lower
    
    if(gross_net(test_net_income * lower) > income)
      lower <- upper - (upper - lower) * 0.9
    test_income <- income * upper
  }}
```

but obviously that does not work. Is a while loop even the "right" way to do this? (I explicitly need a solution involving iteration - inverting the function is not an option for me.)

Comment: `net_income/(1-tax)/(1-social_security)` will give you the gross income. No iteration needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this can be solved algebraically, as given in another answer, a more general approach is to use `uniroot` to find where the function minus target value is zero. e.g. if you want to search the range 0 - 1,000,000

```
net_gross <- function(income) uniroot(function(x){gross_net(x)-income}, c(0, 1e6))
net_gross(1120)
#$root
#[1] 2000  <- The inverse of 1120
#
#$f.root
#[1] 0
#
#$iter
#[1] 1
#
#$init.it
#[1] NA
#
#$estim.prec
#[1] 998000
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I did not know this function. This is probably even much faster than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, invert the funcion is the best way to get the `gross_income` value.

what you have is the following formula:

```
net_income <- (gross_income - gross_income * social_security) * (1 - tax)
```

Which can be rewritten as

```
  net_income <-  gross_income*(1-social_security)*(1-tax)
```

So,solving to get 'gross_income' value:

```
gross_income <- net_income/((1-social_security)*(1-tax))
```

And then, you can build the following function

```
gross_income_solve <- function(net_income, social_security = 0.2, tax = 0.3){
    gross_income <-  net_income/((1-social_security)*(1-tax))
    return(gross_income)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, the original gross_net function is much more complicated and inverting it is not possible. That is why I need a solution involving iteration.